# SQL: payments and orders query

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have 2 tables...
the first one "orders" collects

- memberid
- order_id
- authorization date

the 2nd one "payments" collects

- memberid
- paymentid
- payment number
- last_udpate

a memberid might contain more than 1 card and I need to create a query that brings me the orderid and which payment number has used on each order taking into account when was the last update and authorization date..

I've got till here..

```
SELECT orders.order_id, payments.payments_number
FROM orders
JOIN payments
  ON orders.memberid = payments.memberid
```

I'm a bit lost what subquery should I use to make it work..

Thanks!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: mariadb and heidisql

Comment: Which mariadb version?

Comment: can you be more explicit about the logic to be applied for the dates? "taking into account" is a little bit vague. How should the last_update_date relate to the authorization_date ? Some examples of data and expected outcome would be great.

Comment: mariadb 10.5(x64)

Comment: a userid might have used different payment_numbers and I need to know which payment number has used on each order taking into account the last update has to be before the last authorization date... for example if the user has paid 2 times with different payments_numbers.. the query should bring both payments_numbers (1 for each transaction) if the last_udpate of the 2nd payment number was before the last transaction or should bring the same payment_number if last_update was after the authorization_date... hope it's clear now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you specify the cardinality of 1 to many and I am not sure of which way your cardinality is most accurately represented.

If each `order` has many `payments` then maybe you want something like this.

```
SELECT     o.memberid,
           o.order_id,
           o.[authorization date],           
           p.payments_number,
           p.last_udpate
FROM       orders o
LEFT JOIN  payments p
           ON o.memberid = p.memberid
```

If it is the other way round, maybe something like this

```
    SELECT     o.memberid,
               o.order_id,
               o.[authorization date],           
               p.payments_number,
               p.last_udpate
    FROM       payments p
    LEFT JOIN  orders o
               ON o.memberid = p.memberid
```

Comment: The result should only contain orders.order_id, payments.payments_number and on your query I believe it's missing that the payment_number displayed should be before the authorization_date... example client A paid 1st July with one debitcard and after payment, the user updated his debit 3 times over the month.. by 1st august of august we'll use the last updated debit and the rest should be dismissed..

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think a correlated subquery does what you want:

```
select o.*,
       (select p.payment_number
        from payments p
        where p.memberid = o.memberid and
              p.last_update <= o.authorization_date
        order by last_update desc
        limit 1
       ) as payment_number
from orders o;
```

You can use an additional `join` if you need other columns from `payments`.

Comment: nailed it! Thanks Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to what was proposed but using a CTE could be:

```
;
with cte_partial_results as 
(
SELECT      o.memberid, 
            o.order_id,
            o.[authorization date] as [authorization_date],
            p.paymentid,
            p.[payment number] as payment_number
            p.last_update,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o.memberid, o.order_id ORDER BY p.last_udpate desc) as RowNo
            
FROM        orders o 
LEFT JOIN   payments p ON o.memberid = p.memberid
WHERE       
            p.last_udpate <= o.[authorization date]
            
)
SELECT
        memberid,
        order_id,
        payment_number,
        last_update as most_recent_update
        --add other cols you want.
FROM 
        cte_partial_results 
WHERE       
        RowNo = 1
```